# How big of a capacitor do I need to support my car?

Tags: power-supply, capacitor, components, load-regulation

I drive a 1974 Volkswagen Beetle, I have recently installed a fully electric AC compressor, and I am running a Bosch 75 amp alternator but I find that my car struggles for power when the AC is turned on.

I have read online that installing capacitors to help support the battery during the operation of the AC might help stabilize the voltage from dropping too low.

The battery terminals are also hot to the touch when running the AC compressor. (The compressor is electric powered, and not engine belt driven.)

Can someone provide some intel on the above?

If I decide to install the capacitors:

Max Well 16 V, 500 farads vs 16 V, 1000 farads, which should I choose?

Comment: If the battery terminals are hot, clean them carefully to provide a good connection - the heat is a sign of a poor connection and wasted power.

Comment: I second Peter's comment. Also a capacitor will not help your problem. A capacitor can only help very short term current loads such as for an audio system.

Comment: cap might only help if your alternator and battery are not doing what they should.  What voltage do you see on a multimeter connected to the battery terminals with the meter DC and in AC mode, with the Airconditioner on and off (4 measurements)?  Cap can only stabilize some of the AC reading.

Comment: @Abel ... AC = air conditioner

Comment: @jsotola AC = alternating current, to try to see how much ripple there is.

Comment: The original alternator is about 60 to 80A, so that AC overloads it. Fit a second alternator, but each alternator takes 8 to 12 bhp so expect to accelerate slower…

Comment: Sorry if you were confused by the comment.  I mean take 4 measurements at Battery terminals while the Engine idles to help determine potential impact of a capacitor (since buying an oscilloscope or disconnecting wires to measure current for this is likely overkill): Meter reading Voltage in Direct Current mode with Air Conditioner off, Meter reading Voltage in Alternating Current mode with Air Conditioner off, Meter reading Voltage in Direct Current mode with Air Conditioner on, Meter reading Voltage in Alternating Current mode with Air Conditioner on.

Comment: four of them, about 6 inches each ? but most people just use bricks ;-)

Comment: **1974 Volkswagen Beetle** and **my car struggles for power when the AC is turned on**.  You expect much from the poor Beetle.  Measure voltage at battery and AC compressor.  It is doudtful your alternator will last with long use of the AC compressor.

Answer (score 2):

**Adding a capacitor** to limited current environment **does not fix the problem**, capacitor is just another way to store energy and release it quickly, capacitor tries to recharge after supplying energy to your AC and that **causes more stress to your cars overworked electrical system**, your alternator can't supply enough of current and that causes your Voltage to drops, **Your alternator is your limiting factor** and that's why **getting a better/high-output alternator is the only proper way to fix it**, stressing your alternator or keeping it at "full charge mode" continuously kills it, also you might wanna clean your terminals and shoes, corrosion is the number one "bad contact and heat causer"

Comment: I wanna comment myself, i have seen alot of stuff done when I or one of my buddies install car audio and before anyone got a new alternator we made choices, capacitor is not one of them but multiple batteries and to be precise deep cycle ones, music is dynamic and you usually won't listen all the time so they had time to charge, if you don't wanna buy a new alternator and won't use the ac all the time you can buy second battery but make sure its fully charger before connecting it, alternators won't like to charge for a long period of time. This is wrong and hurts the alternator but it works.

Answer (score 1):

A battery is electric energy storage, so is a capacitor, it is just more short-term.  A capacitor will buffer load spikes, but you are running your AC continuously.  An alternator converts mechanical energy into electrical energy.  A 1974 Volkswagen beetle typically has a 34hp motor (can be had with 50hp but those are rare).  34hp means 25kW.  A 75A alternator will nominally deliver about 1.2kW of electric power (assuming 16V in order to have 14.4V for charging left after rectification) which corresponds to significantly more in mechanical power.

This may be the wrong car to be running a fully electric AC designed for the size and power of a modern car in.  You can meddle with the electrics all you want to, but the electrics including the alternator are intermediate systems and ultimately need to be driven with motor power, and the VW beetle does not have oodles to spare if you want it to keep moving.

Any AC you use will have to be chosen very carefully for drawing power at the bottom of the available power bracket (and given the car size, that will likely be more than sufficient).

Answer (score 0):

The approach you chose is like a doctor prescribing medication without doing any test and going on just the vaguest of symptom descriptions.

There’s no guessing involved in any of it, and no, the capacitor will not solve anything.

That compressor has electrical ratings. Ensure that the alternator can support the compressor load in addition to all the other loads.

Since you likely have no idea how the alternator really performs at idle vs 2000RPM, and how much current the car needs with AC off, you need to measure things first.

Measure the current on the alternator, battery and the compressor to get an idea of how the compressor load distributes between the alternator and the battery. My hunch is that the battery is supplying 25-50% of the AC compressor load. And that’s a bad thing.

Make sure you do worst case tests with all of the major loads turned on: headlights, fog lights (if any), a rated cigarette lighter load, eg. a small inverter, radio blasting, fan at the max setting, brake depressed (turns brake lights on), and the car in reverse (reverse light!).

Comment: Good day Sir, i will send the compressor details here and also figure out a way to measure all of the electrical current drawings. And yes, I am not experienced in this sort of things, thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

My comparisons will show you should get a better Alternator.

Ultracap 16V, C = 1000 F, ESR = 1 mohm est RC=T= 1 s

### Assumptions

Battery 50 Ah, 14.2 V C = 100,000 F est. ESR depends on condition and % of 5V/CCR rate. If new battery, 500 = CCR then ESR = 10 mohm and
RC=T= 1000 s .

The effect is that the ultracap being much lower ESR causes bigger surge currents on the 6 diodes in the alternator for the 3 phase alternator.  The Caps act as near short circuit at 1 mohm being perhaps lower than the diode Rs improves peak voltage slightly under full load.  But at a risk of Alternator damage.

The peak diode current and duration must be compared against the datasheet and derated for a reasonable lifespan.  Also the I^2*ESR power dissipation means a quadratic increase in diode power peak power which may exceed their rating and stress the wirebonds and junction towards fusing at a faster rating or burning open. although duty cycle will decrease, the cost/benefits of slightly improved peak voltage at the expense if increases stress on the diode bridge willmshorten the life of the alternator if embedded.

### Recommendation

trade-up for a larger compatible Alternator.

Comment: do you know of an alternator that would fit a volkswagen beetle classic?
My car's case is a bit different in a sense that the alternator needs to have a shaft at the back of it to pull the fan that is inside the fan shroud. 

So far i am only able to find this bosh 75 amp type which has the shaft from behind

Comment: So in short, i would risk causing the alternator to burn out if i add the super caps?

Means the diode will burn out fast from this ?

Comment: Yes that's what I predict

Comment: This can be simulated in Falstad's

Comment: A 75A alternator is an AC alternator.  Those are pretty universally claw-pole alternators that degress gracefully under overload conditions.  I doubt you'll manage to burn it out but voltage may easily become too low for doing battery recharge duty.  Larger alternators really make no sense with a 25kW motor.

Comment: You need TWO 49 years old VW little cars. One to drive the cars and the second to drive the AC.